# My ohmmeters don't behave as the book "make: electronics" describe

Tags: resistance, books, ohmmeter

Here's the (low end) devices I own. One is an HoldPeak HP-90EPC, the other is an GBC KDM-110

[image]

I am following the book ["Make: Electronics"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920031826.do) by Charles Platt and I am at the very beginnings, where it suggests to:

- measure the resistance of two points of my tongue, wet
- measure the resistance of two points of my tongue, dry

**I get about the same results, or the same range, beacause I don't get a single reading but plenty which change very dynamically every second.**
Also,

- measure the resistance of two parts of your body, then move the probes closer or farther away and see how the resistance increases when they are more distant from each other

**This is not happening.** It looks like my body is about 18 megaohm resistant no matter where I touch the skin - either a couple centimeters apart or on one leg and the arm of the other side of the body.

Same goes for water. If I put the probes into water, the reading is ranging apparently random and seems not to take into account the distance between the probes.

Are both my devices junk?
Or, there is a reason why this could actually make any sense?

Comment: Where do you get 18 megaohm from?

Comment: I read that on the autoranging (blue) ohmmeter.

Comment: They are autoranging.  Most likely, the readings on your tongue don't stay steady enough for the autorange to work.

Comment: Just before O.L.? It’s a good exercise to understand the danger of electrocution but just like you discovered, it varies a lot with contact pressure and also from person to person.

Comment: Short the probes on one meter together.  It should read near zero ohms.  If not, there's something broken.

Comment: Correction:  The blue one is autoranging, the yellow is not.

Comment: With an auto-ranging meter, you must be very careful reading the display - note carefully where the decimal point is, and any range indicators ("M","K", etc).  I think an auto-ranging meter is a poor choice for a beginner, since they can easily be mis-read.

Comment: I confirm that the yellow unit is not autoranging.
In both devices when the probes are shorted I read 0 ohms so they are not so screwed up.
I don't know what O.L. means.

Comment: The "experiments" described are at the edge of what multimeters are useful for, and IMO, the results will be very variable, different for each meter and operator.  It's sort of a silly exercise.  Don't worry about it, and move on.

Comment: "OL" indicates "Overload" or "over range" - the reading is too high to be displayed.  The "1" at the far left of the yellow meter's display also means "Over Range".  On the resistance range, these indications will be shown when there is no connection between the leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any info for the HP-90EPC, but most of the other meters in the family are only good to 20MegΩ. When I did this on myself with a meter that's accurate to 100MegΩ the resistance did not change with distance. When I put it on the same arm I got 25MegΩ and also about the  same when measuring on opposite hands.

This is a poor experiment since conductivity of the skin is determined by moisture content (anybody that has had to wear a wrist strap with a conductivity monitor in dry climates can relate).

The best thing to do to demonstrate resistivity of materials vs distance would be to try a long piece of metal or wire (the thinner the better). The resistivity also needs to be higher than that of the probes (like in the ohms range).

Comment: Thank you. So it's the book thats "wrong" here in suggesting a poor experiment, rather than my meters.

Comment: I think so, skin is pretty variable, what might work for the author might not work for anyone else. If your going to do this again, you might want a more sensitive meter also.